# Best way of testing if an NSImage / CGImageRef is completely transparent

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nsimage

I have an image with tiles that I am splitting up and creating individual tiles with.

However, these images typically contain completely blank areas (tiles in this case) that I wish to exclude. These areas are completely transparent.

Now, how do I go about detecting them? Could read the tile pixel by pixel, by way of `NSBitmapImageRep` but that doesn't sound very efficient.

So what is the best way of testing the transparency of the tile (they are cropped to a `CGImageRef`, then converted to an `NSImage` - if that helps)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind using using a 10.6-only call, then you could try the `NSImage` method

```
hitTestRect:withImageDestinationRect:context:hints:flipped:
```

This would be *easier* than checking pixel by pixel, but I don't know whether it would be more efficient. Somewhere down the line, those pixels have to be checked...